# What is an ideal age duration for a permanent bonding to happen between parents and child?

Tags: parents, working-parents, adult-child

My brother (age: 37) is least attached to our parents. At the time of his birth, our parents had left him with our grandmother. He saw our parents, for the first time, at the age of 3 years. He has lived with them after that till his high school.

Could that be one of the reasons for detachment?
What is an ideal age duration for a permanent bonding to happen between the parents and their children?

Comment: What do you mean by _age duration_?

Comment: @DaveClarke means: 0-3 years of age or 6-12 years of age etc.

Comment: I would say, 0–_age of child_ is the ideal age for permanent bonding to occur between a child and its parents.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Dave here. This question doesn't really make sense - the more time the better, but there is no minimum or a specific threshold below which things will not work. VTC as opinion-based.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on SE CogSci and have been posted there. It should be merged.  http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/does-initial-0-3-years-of-age-have-any-effects-for-a-permanent-bonding-to-happen

Comment: @user462608 I am currently drafting an answer for your question posted on CogSci. Please refrain from double posting across the sites, it's only in rare cases that a question can be appropriately cross posted. It is a good fit for CogSci. Cheers

Comment: @ThinksALot I know cross posting is bad. I did not report this one for closure yet since I wasn't sure if the same question on cogsci would be accepted. This question had received several close votes here.

Comment: @user462608 I can see you are not a new user, I am making this comment for others that visit the site, more so than to educate you. I totally understand. The question, as it stands for CogSci is borderline self help, but if anyone comments, we can easily edit it to make it on topic, am getting you some info for your question on coggy and nice to see you over there :))

Comment: @user462608 let me know what oyu think http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/does-initial-0-3-years-of-age-have-any-effects-for-a-permanent-bonding-to-happen/4742#4742

Answer (score 4):

Research into attachment disorders like [reactive attachment disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_attachment_disorder) show that inattentive primary caregivers or sudden changes of primary caregivers under age 3 or so can have permanent effects on a child's ability to bond with future caregivers, no matter how stable the relationship is after that point.  It's something foster and adoptive parents are warned about and trained to handle.

Note that doesn't mean everyone with that kind of instability ends up having attachment issues.  Nor does it mean you can't form a lasting bond with someone you met after age 3.  Nor is a relatively detached relationship necessarily a result of an attachment disorder.  It's just that age 0-3 is when the way you form attachments gets wired into your brain, and it can sometimes be hard to undo if you don't learn it then.

To put it another way, people with psychological attachment issues have problems bonding with *everyone*, not just their parents.  If your brother has other close and lasting relationships with friends or his wife or his own children, it's unlikely the 3 years of being raised by grandparents damaged his ability to bond with your parents, and more likely his detachment is the result of ongoing factors.

Comment: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/classification-of-attachment-styles/4554#4554 if you are interested and there's some more on cog sci cheers